# Is there a name for the operation on vectors $A$ and $B$ that yields $\|A\|\|B\|\cos\theta$?

Tags: trigonometry

The cross product of two vectors (from Wiki) is an operator defined as:
$$\boldsymbol A\times \boldsymbol B=\lVert A\rVert\lVert B\rVert|Sin(\theta)$$
Is there a named operator defined for:
$$\boldsymbol A\times \boldsymbol B=\lVert A\rVert\lVert B\rVert|Cos(\theta)$$
that also results in a scalar (like an area)? If so, what's it's name?

Comment: Dot product. $\;$

Comment: @mr_e_man - I thought the dot product was a vector. I'm looking for a scalar.

Comment: No, the dot product of two vectors is a scalar. The cross product of two vectors is a vector.

Comment: @Quarkly: The cross product is a vector; namely, a vector perpendicular to the given vectors. The expression you've given is its (signed) magnitude.

Comment: @Blue - _" The expression you've given is its (signed) magnitude"_ Then, yes, I'm looking for an operator that gives the **signed** magnitude of the second equation.

Comment: @Quarkly: The cross product of $A$ and $B$ is a vector perpendicular to $A$ and $B$, with signed magnitude $\|A\|\|B\|\sin\theta$ (a scalar). (The sign depends upon how exactly you measure $\theta$.) The dot product of $A$ and $B$ is $\|A\| \|B\|\cos\theta$ (a scalar). (The sign is independent of how you measure $\theta$.)

Answer (score 2):

The reason you are confused is already shown in your question. If $a$ and $b$ are vectors in $\mathbb{R}^3$ and the angle between them is $\theta$, the cross product produces a $\textbf{vector}$ denoted by $a \times b$. This vector satisfies the following property:

\begin{equation*}
\|a \times b\|=\|a\|\|b\||\sin \theta|
\end{equation*}

The equation you have written down is incorrect and makes no sense as cross product does not produce a scalar.

Back to your question, let $a=(a_1,\cdots,a_n) \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $b=(b_1,\cdots,b_n) \in \mathbb{R}^n$. The real dot product produces a $\textbf{scalar}$ denoted by $a \cdot b$, given by the formula:

\begin{equation*}
a\cdot b = a_1b_1+\cdots+a_nb_n=\sum_{i=1}^na_ib_i
\end{equation*}

If $n=2$ or $n=3$, we have the usual notion of angle between $a$ and $b$. Call this angle $\theta$. It can be proven that:

\begin{equation*}
a\cdot b = \|a\|\|b\|\cos \theta
\end{equation*}

This is indeed a signed value. In fact, if $n>3$, we define the angle between two vectors using this formula.

Comment: Thank you. you have surmised my confusion from reading the Wiki article. The issue may be with Mathematica's representation of the result of the 'dot' operation. This may be a syntax problem on my side. Still investigating.